Ubuntu 24.04 and TLP
I was wondering if there are any drawbacks in installing TLP on Ubuntu 24.04?
Unfortunately I cannot find the source, but I read somewhere that TLP might interfere with Ubuntu's programs for battery optimization.
The reason that I'd like to install TLP is that before Ubuntu I was running Debian on my Thinkpad X1 gen 9, and I was getting much more battery time.

The primary alternative to TLP, which is installed by default on the GNOME and KDE variants of most distributions, is power-profiles-daemon (or tuneD, its successor), and they do change some of the same kernel tunables, so generally it is preferred not to run both at the same time (see e.g. TLP FAQ).
If you're seeing significant improvement in battery life when you're using TLP over PPD after configuring it though, and this is important to you, there is no reason not to use TLP instead. TLP is in the official repositories, and all that's required is that you turn off or uninstall PPD (e.g. by running systemctl mask power-profiles-daemon.service as root) after which you should see no issues with multiple daemons trying to change the same settings. Most linux distributions, including Ubuntu, are configurable enough that you can switch out components like that, or even manually tune the kernel parameters yourself, should you wish to do so.

Thank you for your answer. The funny thing is that in the past I didn't disable any daemon on my Debian installation, I simply installed alongside TLP.
